# How to force range loop to be executed at least once

Tags: python-3.x

In python, we can use the following loop:

```
for k in range(n, m):
   pass
```

where `n`and `m`are two integers.
If `n == m` the loop is ignored (doesn't get executed). How to force the program to execute the loop at least once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way:

```
for k in range(n, max(n+1,m)):
```